# Investment approach infinity

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We know that the value of an investment, $y(t)$, which is compounded continusouly at the interest rate k is governed by the equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = ky$. If the interest rate is related to the size of the investment by $k = \frac{\sqrt(y)}{60}$ then we have the equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{y^{3/2}}{60}.$

a) If one initially invests $400 what is the value of your investment at later times? (it looks like this is an equation not a specific number).

b) For a given initial investment, $y_0$, determine the time at which the worth of the investment approaches !.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Are you sure you wrote the problem correctly?

Comment: @Amzoti Yeah, it's correct. Please let me know if you would like a specific clarification.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil , the question comes more or else right from the book. It's not a lesson but additional info on separable differential equations in the back of the book (after the answers and appendix). I'm going to edit the post a re-word exactly as it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have the differential equation

$$y'(t) = a y^{3/2}$$

where $a=1/60$, with $y(0)$ being given.  To solve:

$$y^{-3/2} dy = a dt \implies -2/\sqrt{y} = a t + C$$

where $C=-2/\sqrt{y(0)}$.

Then we have

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{y(t)}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{y(0)}}-a t$$

This goes to $\infty$ when

$$t=\frac{2}{a \sqrt{y(0)}} = \frac{120}{\sqrt{y(0)}} = 6$$

**EDIT**

This answers (b), which was the original question.  (a) asks for the form of $y(t)$ when $y(0)=400$.  Doing the algebra on my previous equation, I get

$$y(t) = \left ( \frac{1}{20}-\frac{1}{120} t\right)^{-2} = \frac{400}{\left (1-\displaystyle\frac{t}{6}\right)^2}$$

Comment: @rlgordonma Where did you get 120/sqrt(y(0)) from?

Comment: @jonny: $y \rightarrow \infty$ when the RHS = 0.  $2/a = 2/(1/60) = 120$.

Comment: @rlgordonma OK, I'm trying to see why the other answer is different.

Comment: Where did your y(t) go in the last two lines? I'm getting t=60((2/sqrt(y(0))-2/sqrt(y(t)).

Comment: @PatrickNommensen: I also see that the OP added a part (a) in which he asks for the value of $y(t)$.  My form still answers the question.

Comment: I understand, thanks. Good to see discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are continuously compounding interest at a nominal rate of $k$ per annum, you are correct that the equation is $\frac {dy}{dt} = ky$.  If the interest rate is fixed, the solution is $y=y(0)\exp(kt)$.  This never goes to infinity in finite time.  If you are given $k=\frac 1{60}\sqrt y$, the equation becomes $\frac {dy}{dt}=\frac 1{60}y^{\frac 32}$.  Integrating this we get $$\int y^{-\frac 32} dy=\int \frac 1{60} dt \\
-2y^{-\frac 12}=\frac t{60}+C\\
\frac 1{\sqrt y}=-\frac C2-\frac t{120}\\\sqrt y=-\frac 1{\frac C2+\frac t{120}}$$ Since $y \gt 0$, we must have $C \lt 0,$ so we will put $C'=-C$ to get $$\sqrt y=\frac 2{C'-\frac t{60}}\\\sqrt y=\frac {120}{60C'-t}$$  At $t=0$ we have $C'=\frac 2{\sqrt {y(0)}}$ So we have $$\sqrt y=\frac {120}{\frac {120}{\sqrt {y(0)}}-t}$$ which becomes infinite at $$t=120y(0)^{-\frac 12}$$

Comment: @rlgordonma:  found and fixed.  Now we agree.  Thanks